# Error from server (Timeout): error when creating "STDIN": Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout 30s

Tags: elasticsearch, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to [Deploy the Elasticsearch cluster](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/0.9/k8s-quickstart.html#k8s-deploy-elasticsearch), yet running into following error (timeout):

```
$ cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
> apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1alpha1
> kind: Elasticsearch
> metadata:
>   name: quickstart
> spec:
>   version: 7.2.0
>   nodes:
>   - nodeCount: 1
>     config:
>       node.master: true
>       node.data: true
>       node.ingest: true
> EOF
Error from server (Timeout): error when creating "STDIN": Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout 30s
$ echo $?
1
$ time kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.3", GitCommit:"2d3c76f9091b6bec110a5e63777c332469e0cba2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T11:13:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13+", GitVersion:"v1.13.7-gke.19", GitCommit:"bebe882824db5431820e3d59851c8fb52cb41675", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-07-26T00:09:47Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

real    0m2.085s
user    0m0.061s
sys 0m0.019s
$
```

Please advise.

---

via file instead of stdin:

```
$ kubectl apply -f ./elasticsearch.yaml
Error from server (Timeout): error when creating "./elasticsearch.yaml": Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout 30s
$
```

`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces=true`:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces=true
NAMESPACE             NAME                                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
elastic-system        elastic-operator-0                                       1/1     Running   1          2m20s
gitlab-managed-apps   certmanager-cert-manager-6df979599b-njkwf                1/1     Running   0          4m33s
gitlab-managed-apps   ingress-nginx-ingress-controller-7cf6944677-n4bkj        1/1     Running   0          5m58s
gitlab-managed-apps   ingress-nginx-ingress-default-backend-7f7bf55777-rv699   1/1     Running   0          5m58s
gitlab-managed-apps   prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5d5958bc-qzm2n             1/1     Running   0          4m9s
gitlab-managed-apps   prometheus-prometheus-server-5c476cc89-2j4vw             2/2     Running   0          4m9s
gitlab-managed-apps   runner-gitlab-runner-7f886d8cbb-5lpfh                    1/1     Running   0          3m25s
gitlab-managed-apps   tiller-deploy-5c85978967-2hdcb                           1/1     Running   0          6m29s
kube-system           calico-node-j6gq9                                        2/2     Running   0          21m
kube-system           calico-node-vertical-autoscaler-579467d76c-7vgcn         1/1     Running   4          23m
kube-system           calico-typha-65bfd5544b-dp8bk                            1/1     Running   0          21m
kube-system           calico-typha-horizontal-autoscaler-847fc7bc8d-vwz6b      1/1     Running   0          23m
kube-system           calico-typha-vertical-autoscaler-dc95cc498-qzfm2         1/1     Running   4          23m
kube-system           event-exporter-v0.2.4-5f88c66fb7-8c52j                   2/2     Running   0          23m
kube-system           fluentd-gcp-scaler-59b7b75cd7-82jzd                      1/1     Running   0          23m
kube-system           fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-cq2sr                                 2/2     Running   0          22m
kube-system           heapster-v1.6.1-7447959494-pdvl5                         3/3     Running   0          22m
kube-system           ip-masq-agent-wwff4                                      1/1     Running   0          23m
kube-system           kube-dns-6987857fdb-67fjq                                4/4     Running   0          23m
kube-system           kube-dns-autoscaler-bb58c6784-kk8nv                      1/1     Running   0          23m
kube-system           kube-proxy-gke-test-default-pool-56270fe6-k846           1/1     Running   0          23m
kube-system           l7-default-backend-fd59995cd-9bt9g                       1/1     Running   0          23m
kube-system           metrics-server-v0.3.1-57c75779f-vxn2g                    2/2     Running   0          22m
kube-system           prometheus-to-sd-zwcr5                                   1/1     Running   0          23m
$
```

`kubectl -n elastic-system logs statefulset.apps/elastic-operator`:

```
$ kubectl -n elastic-system logs statefulset.apps/elastic-operator
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.3942742,"logger":"manager","msg":"Setting up client for manager"}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.3945758,"logger":"manager","msg":"Setting up manager"}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.3946166,"logger":"manager","msg":"Exposing Prometheus metrics on /metrics","port":8080}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.527746,"logger":"manager","msg":"Setting up scheme"}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5363684,"logger":"manager","msg":"Setting up controllers","roles":["all"]}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5364962,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"license-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.536699,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"license-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5368743,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"trial-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5369632,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"apmserver-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5370846,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"apmserver-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.53719,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"apmserver-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5372877,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"apmserver-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5373478,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"apmserver-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5374265,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"apm-es-association-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.537455,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"apm-es-association-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.53751,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"kibana-association-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5376432,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"kibana-association-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5377114,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"kibana-association-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5377367,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"kibana-association-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5378115,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"elasticsearch-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.537839,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"elasticsearch-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5379903,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"elasticsearch-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5380125,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"elasticsearch-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5380402,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"elasticsearch-controller","source":"channel source: 0xc0005bc190"}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.538163,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"kibana-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5381901,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"kibana-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5382109,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"kibana-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5382414,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"kibana-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5382638,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting EventSource","controller":"kibana-controller","source":"kind source: /, Kind="}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5382783,"logger":"manager","msg":"Setting up webhooks"}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.5690362,"logger":"manager","msg":"Starting the manager","uuid":"c80dcec9-c5d8-11e9-944f-8a11f67f61c1","namespace":"elastic-system","version":"0.9.0","build_hash":"8280d41","build_date":"2019-07-29T14:26:01Z","build_snapshot":"false"}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.669517,"logger":"kubebuilder.webhook","msg":"installing webhook configuration in cluster"}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.669637,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting Controller","controller":"trial-controller"}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.6697185,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting Controller","controller":"apmserver-controller"}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.6696646,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting Controller","controller":"elasticsearch-controller"}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.66953,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting Controller","controller":"apm-es-association-controller"}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.669866,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting Controller","controller":"kibana-controller"}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.6695576,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting Controller","controller":"license-controller"}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.669851,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting Controller","controller":"kibana-association-controller"}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.7698772,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting workers","controller":"apmserver-controller","worker count":1}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.7700884,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting workers","controller":"trial-controller","worker count":1}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.770116,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting workers","controller":"kibana-controller","worker count":1}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.7701266,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting workers","controller":"kibana-association-controller","worker count":1}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.7701535,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting workers","controller":"license-controller","worker count":1}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.7701898,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting workers","controller":"apm-es-association-controller","worker count":1}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.7704868,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Starting workers","controller":"elasticsearch-controller","worker count":1}
{"level":"info","ts":1566587049.8052213,"logger":"kubebuilder.webhook","msg":"starting the webhook server."}
$
```

Comment: are you having trouble with any other deployments or just this one?

Comment: @PatrickW I just deleted of my entire cluster and re-did everything from scratch (I was able to connect to my GitLab and install application without any issue) yet still getting same error as before for elastic(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Disabling network policy enforcement](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/network-policy#disabling_network_policy_enforcement)

> gcloud container clusters update [CLUSTER_NAME] --no-enable-network-policy

---

https://github.com/elastic/cloud-on-k8s/issues/1673#issuecomment-529132929